# Получение DOM элемента

Tags: dom, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, как можно из GeoObject получить DOM элемент?
Мне нужно на карте при клике на метку выводить свой элемент, который позиционируется относительно DOM элеметов.

Comment: Ок, вот мой код который работал в 2.0 при клике на метку: oEvent.get('domEvent').originalEvent.srcElement

В 2.1 как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вам помогут эти примеры: 
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/dom_event_manager и https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_properties

Проще всего слушать событие клика на метке средствами API.

Comment: Спасибо! но мне нужно отслеживать именно клик на метку, а не просто событие клик по карте. Проблема в том, что метки - это результаты поиска, а не созданные мной.

Comment: система событий распространяется и на объекты на карте, просто случайте событие клика не на карте, а на метке https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IDomEventEmitter-docpage/#event-click

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/domEvent.manager-docpage/ - здесь нужно указывать Id, у меня только id контейнера с картой :(

Comment: приведите в теле вопроса свой код с картой и объектами и подробнее опишите, что хотите сделать в итоге, только тогда получится посоветовать что-то дельное

Comment: @Иван id меткам по умолчанию задаются при их добавлении через [ObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/object-manager/about.html?lang=ru)